# "Pointer" to class to shorten class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Learning UML, I'm facing a problem with the arrows to classes.

For example, I have this diagram:

[image]

As you can see, it's kind of a mess. How is the notation to "reference" a class to another part of the diagram, so I can avoid drawing the arrows? I would like it to be like the following diagram, but keeping the information about the inheritance of the classes.

[image]

Any information or alternative will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use newly done UML tools you should be able when you move the classifier and see the link to move at the same time. 
I mean you click on the classifier in order to select it and then move slowly with the mouse

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. I want to know if UML has a mean to "reference" another part of the diagram without using a visible link. Kinda like a shortcut.

Comment: In UML you have the graphical information available into the class diagram and the model behind. I mean that from a model you can create UML views using a class diagram or other diagrams. It means that you can have visible or none visible link but the model always remain the same.

Comment: So is possible to create a sub-view on a class diagram? (I'm not using other diagrams). If so, how is it done? Any particular notation? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. You can open the UML model and then drag and drop the existing model elements inside an empty diagram. If you use a good tool you will have options to show hide links, compartments, layout etc.... in order to recreate a class diagram from an existing model.